# issues while parsing through a .txt file

Tags: python

Ok, so I am working on a script that parses through a `.txt` file and based on certain strings that it finds in the file, makes certain recommendations.

Let's say that I want to parse through the `parameters.txt` file which looks something like:

```
ztta/roll_memory = 250000
shm = 5000
```

Now, the code I am using to do this is:

```
  a = 'ztta/roll_memory = 250000'
  b = 'shm = 5000'
  with open('parameter.txt', 'r') as myfile:
  data = myfile.read()
  if a in data: 
     print("the value of ztta/roll_memory is correct --> PASS")
  else:
     print("the value of ztta/roll memory is incorrect --> FAIL")
  if b in  data:
     print("the value of shm is correct --> PASS")
  else:
     print("the value of shm is incorrect --> FAIL")
```

The issue here is that if one of the parameters in the `.txt` file would have a value like:

```
ztta/roll_memory = 2500 (**instead of 250000**), the if statement would still be triggered.
```

Thank you

Comment: Yeah. Because `'aaa'` is also in `'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'` .... but  `'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'`  is not in `'aaa'`. Test for `'ztta/roll_memory = 250000\n` and `shm = 5000\n` - inlcuding the line delimiter should fix it - unless you might have spaces in ... then use regex.

Comment: @PatrickArtner that did the trick, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way of putting `if a in data` is:

```
if 'ztta/roll_memory = 250000' in 'ztta/roll_memory = 250000':
```

You can see that the substring `a` in enclosed in the comparative string,
regardless of how many zeros trail it.

Another way of putting it:

```
if 'ab' in 'abc' # True
if 'ab' in 'abd' # True
if 'hello00' in 'hello00000' # True
```

---

On an aside, your code is not scalable. You should try reading in the parameters as `ints` instead of strings. I.e.,

```
good_values = {'ztta/roll_memory': 250000, 'shm': 5000}
params = {}

with open('parameter.txt','r') as myfile:
    for line in myfile:
        line_array = [x.strip() for x in line.split('=')]
        params[line_array[0]] = int(line_array[-1])

for key in params:
    if params[key] == good_values[key]:
        print("the value of {0} is correct --> PASS".format(key))
    else:
        print("the value of {0} is incorrect --> FAIL".format(key))
```